# Проблема с вводом массива

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не компилируется код. Не могу понять, почему возникает ошибка.

Проблема с 6 строкой:

```
spisok[i] = input()
```

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

```
spisok = list()
print('Определите количество студентов вашей группы.')
KolStud= int(input())
for i in range(KolStud):
    print('Введите ФИО['+str(i)+']: ')
    spisok[i] = input()

print(spisok)
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `spisok[i] = input()` на `spisok.append(input())`

Comment: Помогло, да, спасибо! =)

Comment: чутка изменил ответ для вашего случая

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как уже отметил  @S. Nick, ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь передать значение ввода элементам массива, которых еще не существует, вместо этого - воспользуйтесь конструкцией :

```
.append()
```

которая добавляет элементы в конец списка, либо же, если размер массива известен, то можно создать пустой массив на заданное число элементов, и потом уже заполнять.

```
spisok = [0] * KolStud
```

Comment: Допустим я создал массив так:
`spisok = [5]`
А потом, чтобы заполнить его не подходит такой метод `spisok[0]=256`
Нужно заполнять методом `spisok.insert(0, 256)`

Comment: @ArthurAlunts а вы проверяли, прежде чем такое писать?